# How to make Dropdown shows Image & Text at Toolbar Form(VB.net)?

Tags: windows, vb.net, toolbar, toolstrip

I have my Visual Studio 2010 and currently I'm developing it using Vb.net language.
My purpose is actually to make a Toolbar Item that look [like this (it shown Image, Text and Dropbox)](http://s22.postimg.org/w13om85sh/Sample_How_TOMake_Drop_Down_With_Image.png) --> known as one item. (I edit it a little bit to show my purposes).

But In VB.net here VS2010, I found that, too much works need;
1) Make a ToolStrip
1) Add an Item of SplitButton (or DropDownButton), 
2) Add another item as Label

But by doing that way, Our
position for the DropDown become like this;

[Look!
(Image, DropDown, and Text)](http://s24.postimg.org/npslsxoyt/Demo_Tool_Bar_Combobox_Image_Text_VBNet_How.png) --> Strange.

It should be
(Image, Text, and DropDown) --> Correct. Shouldn't it be?

So
What are the solutions for this case ?

Comment: I believe there is built in image storing accessible from the edit panel, might be better for those of us that can't access dropbox :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the DisplayStyle of your DropDownButton to ImageAndText.  Then you can change your Image and Text properties and have them both display in the dropdown like in your first screenshot.